# Why one url the doesn't require an auth asks for token when placed below a url that requires auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I obeserved a weird error(maybe) while testing my apis. I have three views handleing the api requests. Two doen't require auth **(searchListing, listListing)** and on requires auth **(retrieveListing)**. Weirdly if I keep the **'search'** below the **'str:slug''** url (urlpatern_1) it says **Authentication credentials were not provided.** However if I move the **search** above the **'str:slug''** it works perfectly.

```
urlpatterns_1 = [
    
    path('', views.listListing , name= 'listListing'),
    path('<str:slug>', views.retrieveListing , name= 'retrieveList'),
    path('search', views.searchListing , name= 'searchList'),

]
```

```
urlpatterns_2 = [
    
    path('', views.listListing , name= 'listListing'),
    path('search', views.searchListing , name= 'searchList'),
    path('<str:slug>', views.retrieveListing , name= 'retrieveList'),

]
```

But weirdly again the **'listListing'** is unaffected by its position.

Please explain me why is this happening

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def listListing(request):
    pass

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def retrieveListing(request, slug):
     pass

@api_view(['GET'])
def searchListing(request):
    pass
```

Comment: My feel is that `search` also passed to `retrieveListing`. Can you double check that by putting some print statement on each function...

Comment: @RajaSimon Both the urls are calling their respective views

Comment: @RitankarBhattacharjee Raja Simon is indeed correct. If `<str:slug>` is above `search`, then Django is matching `/search` url with the first url and the literal value `"search"` is interpreted as slug. Therefore the first view is called. Solution is to keep catch-all patterns at the bottom of urls.

Comment: @xyres I am not aware of the cath all patterns, can you please put up an ans showing an example